# .NET Reflection

Tags: .net, reflection

using :

```
 Dim a As [Assembly] = [Assembly].LoadFile("C:\test.exe")


 Dim testTP As Type
 testTP = a.GetType("SplashScreen", True, True)

 obj1 = Activator.CreateInstance(testTP)

 obj1.show()
```

my prog made reflection to test.exe > SplashScreen loaded , also obj1 filled

when SplashScreen disposed -> MainForm loaded > the obj1 isnothing!

when try to access obj1 VS say :

> AccessibilityObject = {"Cannot
>   access a disposed object. Object name:
>   'SplashScreen'."}

I want always obj1 filled from the active form!! how????

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of the phrase "I want always obj1 filled from the active form". Please explain what do you want exactly.

Comment: when SplashScreen disposed -> MainForm loaded ===== how 'fill' obj1 from MainForm or somehow manipulate the Instance of MainForm (?)

Comment: Can you provide some more details?  Where is this code within your app?  Where is *obj1* accessed, that causes the problem?  Does *obj1* attempt to do something with the *SplashScreen*?

Comment: 1-
obj1 is a object 

2-
I use reflection to CreateInstance of test.exe which in normal cases (no reflection, if you run it by hand) starts with "SplashScreen"

3-
The need = I want to manipulate the MainForm (of course I can start MainForm from start, but needed 1st load SplashScreen)


4-imagine that I have 2buttons on my prog the first made the reflection , the second 'ask' obj1 which is public variable

Comment: ok here is a sample PRJ try to make reflection to "SplashScreen" and then manipulate "MainForm"     http://archiv.to/GET/FILE4BFD91276809A

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is written, what you want to do is not possible.  You instantiate an instance of the SplashScreen; when the timer ticks, it launches the main form and then disposes itself.  ("`Me.Close()`")  Your instance of this object is now invalid.  Furthermore, you could not update your object to the instance of the main form, since they are different types.

If you want to force the splash screen to always display when the form is opened, you should handle this in the main form Load event.  Then, get your handle to the main form (which you want) and let it handle the splash screen.